# AD Microsoft Login 400 bad request headers too long ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, browser, webserver, azure-active-directory

My asp.net mvc application works as expected on localhost and logs in on every browser with ease. I am using Azure Active directory to log in to the application, I published my application to a web server and now I get a 400 bad request from every browser.

I have tried clearing the cache with no luck.
I increased the maxRequest and time.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="2097151"/>
```

I noticed that the browser is attempting to log in but the request is sent over 40 times. I managed to get it working sometimes but once the request is sent to microsoft.login I get the same error.

Does anyone know of a solution to my problem?

Thanks in advance, Adam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, the HTTP headers is determined by both `maxRequestLength` and `MaxFieldLength`, please also increase the value of `MaxFieldLength` and let us know whether it helps. (Refer this [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2020943/-http-400---bad-request-request-header-too-long-error-in-internet-info) for the same error message)